# How to loop n items at a time but not stepping only 1 each time? python

Tags: python, list, iteration, generator

I have a generator, let's say:

```
x = iter([1,2,3,4,5,6])
```

And if i want to loop 3 items at a time but step only 1 each time, i want to get:

```
1 2 3
2 3 4
3 4 5
5 6
```

I have tried looping two at a time but it steps 2 each time:

```
x = iter([1,2,3,4,5,6])
x = list(x)
for i,j in zip(x[::2],x[1::2]):
    print i,j
```

[out]:

```
1 2
3 4
5 6
```

I have tried looping n at a time but it also steps n:

```
from itertools import izip_longest

def grouper(n, iterable, fillvalue=None):
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return izip_longest(fillvalue=fillvalue, *args)

x = iter([1,2,3,4,5,6])

for i,j in grouper(3,x):
    print i,j
print
```

[out]:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 11, in <module>
    for i,j in grouper(3,x):
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

I have tried just access +n each time i loop:

```
x = iter([1,2,3,4,5,6])
x = list(x)

for i,j in enumerate(x):
    print x[i], x[i+1], x[i+2]
```

[out]:

```
1 2 3
2 3 4
3 4 5
4 5 6
5 6
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 26, in <module>
    print x[i], x[i+1], x[i+2]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Question:

- Can I not change the generator into a list before looping and accessing more than one value at a time but stepping only 1 each time?
- Other than using the last solution i have, how to else achieve the desired iteration?

Comment: The desired output appears to be incorrect (which sounds daft, I know). Shouldn't the last line be `4 5 6`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe good dupe target... I'll make sure we add that to the sopython list :)

Comment: what's the sopython list? where's that?

Comment: @alvas http://sopython.com/wiki/common-questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `tee`, `islice` and `izip_longest` as a base, and adapt the "stop" condition, eg:

```
from itertools import tee, islice, izip_longest

data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
iters = [islice(it, n, None) for n, it in enumerate(tee(data, 3))]
res = list(izip_longest(*iters))
# [(1, 2, 3), (2, 3, 4), (3, 4, 5), (4, 5, 6), (5, 6, None), (6, None, None)]
```

An example stop condition might be:

```
from itertools import takewhile
res = list(takewhile(lambda L: None not in L, izip_longest(*iters)))
# [(1, 2, 3), (2, 3, 4), (3, 4, 5), (4, 5, 6)]
```

Comment: doesn't it destroy the generator structure and create the whole object in memory instead?

Comment: @lejlot not following...

Comment: generator's are space efficient objects, they do not actually store the whole list in the memory. Isn;t your solution breaking this feature?

Comment: @lejlot if you're referring to the `list` part - that's purely to demonstrate the output - the `izip_longest` could be iterated over normally if needs be

Comment: and you could switch the iters from a list to a generator to avoid generating that list.

Comment: @M4rtini I suppose one could - but for 3 items, it hardly seems worth it :)